# Print counting in loop java

Tags: java, loops, printing

I have a java program that simulates values and returns them. But I want to see how far the simulation is by printing the current state.

Ex:

```
System.out.print("Number of simulations: ");
for(int i=0;i<NUMBER_OF_SIMULATIONS;i++){

/* Do my calcutions*/

System.out.print("\b" + i);
}
```

I thougth this was possible, but the output is:
Number of simulations:  0?1?2?3?4?5?6?7?8?9?10?11?12?

I only want to see the current state, so not a counter.
So if i++ current i removes and i+1 will shown.

Comment: What were you expecting to see? Can you give an example of a valid input and the expected output?

Comment: try `\r` instead of `\b`

Comment: I want to get 0 , then 0 removes and 1 will be on the place of 0 ect..

Answer (score 1):

`\b` will go back 1 char. As Pawel Veselov said, use `\r` to go to the beginning of the line.
Another important thing is that, depending on where you're testing the output (IDE), it won't work as expected. You should test in a shell (Windows cmd or Linux terminal) in order to see the real result.

Answer (score 0):

If you where expecting to edit the value to have one line being:

```
Number of simulations: 0 //and then editing just the number to have

Number of simulations: 1
```

Its not possible on the command line to my knowledge.. every time you call System.out.print you are writing/adding the value into the "out" stream, hence the count being added every time is called at the end of the line with print().

You would need to add a new line for every time you print it.

```
System.out.println("Number of Simulations: " + i);
```

And that will give you a new line everytime.

Edit: Its not what you want, but thats a cleaner way to visualize it and how programs normally log steps.